# How to write conditional rendering with map() on an array if there is no values in the array?

Tags: arrays, react-native, conditional-rendering

The screen that I'm trying to code has a conditional rendering which shows whether there is any events are present or not. If there is events in the array, then it should run through a map() and display all of them as lists.

But when there is no values in the array, the map() still executes and I get an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null".

I couldn't do much as I'm a beginner in React and React Native!

```
class Home extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      events: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getDataFromStorage('Oh123456');
  }

  async getDataFromStorage(key){
    await AsyncStorage.getItem(key).then((res) => {
      res = JSON.parse(res);
      this.setState({ events: res });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const noEventsFound = (
      <View>
        <Heading>
          <H1>No Events Found!</H1>
        </Heading>
      </View>
    );


    const loadAllEventsNow = this.state.events.map((event) => (
      <OhList eventName={event.name} />
    ));

    return (
      <ImageBackground source={backgroundImage} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          { !this.state.events ? noEventsFound : loadAllEventsNow }
        </View>
        <View>
          <OhButton color="#7BE78A" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')}>CREATE AN EVENT</OhButton>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

I expect the screen to show "No events found" on the screen when there is no events in the array and if there are any events, then a list of events.

Comment: Please add your sample json data

Comment: Thanks for responding! Here is the sample json data.

events = [{
        name: "Graduation",
        date: "Dec 2",
        time: "10AM",
        hosts: "John",
        active: true,
      }];

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **this.state.events** is an array you can replace

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      { !this.state.events ? noEventsFound : loadAllEventsNow } 
</View>
```

**with this**:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      { Array.isArray(this.state.events) && this.state.events.length < 1 ? noEventsFound : loadAllEventsNow } 
</View>
```